# HiDPI modify dpi Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, hdpi

With Gnome 3.18, I know how to increase the windows scaling, with the gnome tweak extension. But, the windows scaling is an integer value. Windows scaling defined to 1 (default), the elements of the interface is too small on my labtop 14’ with 1980x1280, HiDPI. But windows scaling defined to 2, the elements are really too big, even after reboot. So, please, tell me how to change the “global” DPI with terminal with decimal value, instead of windows scaling, for Gnome 3.18. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create .Xresources in home and add the line.

> Xft.dpi: [DPI value]

```
$ xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

for 4k display 230 dpi works fine